# if statement skipped/ignored

Tags: python, if-statement

when i run this code, and food is something like -5, it seems to completely skip the if statement and move on to the next part of the function (i only have part of it below)

```
def change_location():
global food
global units
global SP
if food < 0: #problem seems to be here
        print '------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'not enougth food'
        main()
```

the concept is that if you have no food, you cant go to a new location. I wouldn't mind an alternative to this.

Comment: There is no obvious error in this code snippet. Please make some tests and give us more details.

Comment: your indentation is wrong...

Comment: You should print the value of `food` before the if statement. I'm guessing that `food` have a different value from what you expect.

Comment: @Simon With `food == -5`, `food < 0 `is `True`, and the code inside the if statement should be executed.

Comment: Please provide a complete, short program that demonstrates the error you having. In your case, a complete program should fit in 5-10 lines of code. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Comment: An alternative is to not use global variables. You say that if `food` is `-5` do something, but with global variables, the lack of scope means variables can change without you knowing. For all you know `food` might be `5` and not `-5`.

Comment: @SteinarLima: Thanks for the correction - I'm obviously not paying enough attention ...

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that `food` is not a string, because in CPython2, `'-5' < 0` is False:

```
>>> '-5' < 0
False
```

You can test if this is the problem in your code by placing an assert before the if statement:

```
assert not isinstance(food, basestring)
if food < 0:
    ...
```

If `food` is a string (or unicode), the program stop with an `AssertionError` when it reaches the `assert` statement.

If it does turn out that `food` is a string, you will need to track down the source of the problem. When you find where `food` is being defined as a string, you can convert that string into an int using the `int` function:

```
food = int(...)
```

Of course, you could even use `int` in the condition,

```
if int(food) < 0:
```

but if `food` is intended to be an `int`, then this would be a sloppy way to program.

---

From [the CPython2 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons),

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

So, since the word `'float'` comes before `'string'` alphabetically, all floats are ordered less than any string.

In Python3, comparing objects of different type raises a TypeError, thus removing this pitfall.

Comment: im not using Cpython. food is defantely not a string.

Comment: Then you need to help us help you by providing more information. Put `print(repr(food))` and `print(type(food))` before the `if food < 0` statement, and post the output. It would definitely help if you could post a short runnable example demonstrating the problem. Being able to do this is a fantastic skill for debugging. In the process of doing that you would either discover the source of the problem yourself, or produce something which would allow us to identify the problem immediately. However, if that is too hard, it would still help to post the code which defines `food`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably @ubuntu is correct. Here's some quick tips to debug this type of thing

Add a print statement

```
print food
if food < 0: #problem seems to be here
```

Problem is that `-5` and `"-5"` get printed exactly the same. Adding a `repr` helps

```
print repr(food)
if food < 0: #problem seems to be here
```

Now you see that `food` is `'-5'` aha.

It's also a good idea to learn about the debugger

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
if food < 0: #problem seems to be here
```

This will give you a `(Pdb)` prompt in the console. Type "food" and press enter

```
(Pdb) food
'-5'
```

Again, you can easily notice that `food` is a string. This is such a common mistake that those types of comparison are no longer allowed in Python3